# Binding aar Visual Studio (Xamarin)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I'm working with xamarin in Visual Studio and I try to link files (java to C #)
I'm using library bindings (android) to integrate the files, but for some methods this process converts to fail.

Error message

```
Class X does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground (params Object [])'
```

I try to configure the metadata but I can not solve these errors
Someone already saw this problem .. And you know how to solve??

API xml

```
<class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" extends="android.os.AsyncTask" extends-generic-aware="android.os.AsyncTask&lt;java.lang.Object, java.lang.Void, com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.response.base.MobileStatusResponse&gt;" final="false" name="ApiCallAsyncTask" static="false" visibility="public">
    <constructor deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ApiCallAsyncTask" static="false" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.ApiCallAsyncTask" visibility="public">
    <parameter name="p0" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.callback.BaseApiCallAsyncTaskCallback">
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p1" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.request.base.BaseRequest">
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p2" type="boolean">
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p3" type="boolean">
    </parameter>
    </constructor>
<constructor deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ApiCallAsyncTask" static="false" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.ApiCallAsyncTask" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.callback.BaseApiCallAsyncTaskCallback">
</parameter>
<parameter name="p1" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.request.base.BaseRequest">
</parameter>
<parameter name="p2" type="boolean">
</parameter>
</constructor>
<constructor deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ApiCallAsyncTask" static="false" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.ApiCallAsyncTask" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.callback.BaseApiCallAsyncTaskCallback">
</parameter>
<parameter name="p1" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.request.base.BaseRequest">
</parameter>
</constructor>
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="doInBackground" native="false" return="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.response.base.MobileStatusResponse" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="protected">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object...">
</parameter>
</method>
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="onPostExecute" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="protected">
<parameter name="p0" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.response.base.MobileStatusResponse">
</parameter>
</method>
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="writeDataForRequestObject" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="protected">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.net.HttpURLConnection">
</parameter>
<parameter name="p1" type="java.lang.Object">
</parameter>
<exception name="IOException" type="java.io.IOException">
</exception>
</method>
<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="LOCK" static="true" transient="false" type="java.lang.Object" type-generic-aware="java.lang.Object" visibility="protected" volatile="false">
</field>
<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="baseRequest" static="false" transient="false" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.request.base.BaseRequest" type-generic-aware="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.request.base.BaseRequest" visibility="protected" volatile="false">
</field>
<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="blocking" static="false" transient="false" type="boolean" type-generic-aware="boolean" visibility="protected" volatile="false">
</field>
<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="callback" static="false" transient="false" type="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.callback.BaseApiCallAsyncTaskCallback" type-generic-aware="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask.callback.BaseApiCallAsyncTaskCallback" visibility="protected" volatile="false">
</field>
<field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="showDialog" static="false" transient="false" type="boolean" type-generic-aware="boolean" visibility="protected" volatile="false">
</field>
</class>
```

MetaData

```
<metadata>
  <!--
  This sample removes the class: android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.LoadTask:
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='android.support.v4.content']/class[@name='AsyncTaskLoader.LoadTask']" />

  This sample removes the method: android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground:
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='android.support.v4.content']/class[@name='CursorLoader']/method[@name='loadInBackground']" />
  -->

    <!-- There are also some methods that need to have their generic _parameter_ types simplified to `java.lang.Object`.
         Possible error message: Error CS0115: `SomeMethod(..., T, ...)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)
         Possible error message: Error CS0535: `SomeClass' does not implement interface member `SomeMethod(..., Java.Lang.Object,...)' (CS0535)
         Possible error message: Error CS0534: `SomeClass' does not implement inherited abstract member `SomeMethod(..., Java.Lang.Object,...)' (CS0534) -->
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='ApiCallAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='CustomApiCallAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='ExtractZipFileAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='GetApplicationPropertiesApiCallAsyncTaskCallback']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='GetImageBytesAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='GetRegisteredCardsAsyncTask']" />    
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.asynctask']/class[@name='SavePictureAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.asynctask']/class[@name='StoreImageBytesApiCallAsyncTask']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.asynctask']/class[@name='ValidateCheckImagesWithA2iaAsyncTask']" />    
</metadata>
```

Comment: What is the API xml description for `doInBackground`?

Comment: API xml? Sorry.. this my first exp with xamain binding.. where i can see the API xml?

..tnks

Comment: `obj\Debug\api.xml` for the auto-generated one : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Overview

Comment: i edit with all tag about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue most likely sits here:

```
<method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="doInBackground" native="false" return="com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.response.base.MobileStatusResponse" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="protected">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object...">
</parameter>
</method>
```

As you can see here, the method `doInBackground` returns `com.ingomoney.ingosdk.android.http.json.response.base.MobileStatusResponse` and takes a parameter of `java.lang.Object...`. This needs to match exactly what the interface expects if it does not, you need to "dumb" down the object type.

In short you are running into partial generics support, http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/limitations/#Partial_Java_Generics_Support

There's a couple of things you can do:

1. Create a partial class of the class at fault and create an override inside:

i.e.

`protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] params){...}`

2. If you plan to not use this class at all, use `<remove-node>` to remove the class: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#removing-types

There are ways to fix this in the `Metadata.xml` as well, but I'd have to look at a sample. Ideally you might change the `managedReturn`, `managedType`, or even the `argsType`.

Comment: Cool.. i post my Metadata now
I've been trying to use the tag but the rebuild show me same error..

Look my Metadata